# Добавление libcurl в cmake проект \ Qt Creator \ Windows

Tags: c++, curl, cmake, qtcreator, libcurl

Пытаюсь подключить curl к проекту на Qt Creator, в котором используется cmake. В `CMakeLists.txt` файле имею следующее:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(WindowApp_Lab3 VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        mainwindow.cpp
        mainwindow.h
        mainwindow.ui
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(WindowApp_Lab3
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )
# Define target properties for Android with Qt 6 as:
#    set_property(TARGET WindowApp_Lab3 APPEND PROPERTY QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR
#                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android)
# For more information, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-executable.html#target-creation
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(WindowApp_Lab3 SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
# Define properties for Android with Qt 5 after find_package() calls as:
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
    else()
        add_executable(WindowApp_Lab3
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    endif()
endif()

target_link_libraries(WindowApp_Lab3 PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets)

# Qt for iOS sets MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER automatically since Qt 6.1.
# If you are developing for iOS or macOS you should consider setting an
# explicit, fixed bundle identifier manually though.
if(${QT_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 6.1.0)
  set(BUNDLE_ID_OPTION MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER com.example.WindowApp_Lab3)
endif()
set_target_properties(WindowApp_Lab3 PROPERTIES
    ${BUNDLE_ID_OPTION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS WindowApp_Lab3
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(WindowApp_Lab3)
endif()

set(CURL_INCLUDE_DIR C:/curl/curl-8.3.0/builds/libcurl-vc16-x64-debug-static-ipv6-sspi-schannel/include)
set(CURL_LIBRARY C:/curl/curl-8.3.0/builds/libcurl-vc16-x64-debug-static-ipv6-sspi-schannel/lib)

find_package(CURL REQUIRED)

if(LIBCURL_ENABLE)
    include_directories(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CURL_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

При включении в файл `main.cpp` #include "curl/curl.h" получаю ошибку

> main.cpp:3:10: 'curl/curl.h' file not found

Не понимаю, что делаю не так

Comment: `LIBCURL_ENABLE` - уверены, что этот флаг выставлен?

Comment: И еще у вас переменные с путями заданы одни, а используются другие. А `find_package` вообще не известно, срабатывает или нет.